# How do you get json @attributes item in a meteor template

Tags: json, meteor

I have a json that is converted from XML and kept "@attributes"  :

```
{"stop":"1021","route":"0057","direction":"1","departures":{"departure":[
{"@attributes":{"accurate":"1","headsign":"Rennes R"},"content":"2013-03-25T12:00:23+01:00"},
{"@attributes":{"accurate":"0","headsign":"Rennes R"},"content":"2013-03-25T12:20:00+01:00"},
{"@attributes":{"accurate":"0","headsign":"Rennes R"},"content":"2013-03-25T12:40:00+01:00"}]}},...
```

you can here access to the properties in javascript [1] with :

```
departure[0]["@attributes"].accurate
```

but if you want to grab it in a template with Meteor, how do you do this?

[1] [JSON @attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316923/json-attributes)

Comment: i have to wait 7 hours before posting my own answer :( -> solution is here :  http://bit.ly/YstER0

Comment: Probably best to not shorten the URL and offer some disclosure that you're linking to your own site

Comment: @Swadq comments are limited in length and i will put the full content as answer here in 1 hour ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest accessing the field in a function such as

```
Templates.your_template.attributes = function()
{ 
   return this["@attributes"];
}
```

in your template

```
{{attributes}}
```

Comment: thx adrianj98, 3 or 2 mustaches ? i will check if {{{attributes}}}.accurate works fine

Answer (score 0):

the template in the html side will look like this :

```
<template name="status">
   <div class="line {{status}}_line">
       {{stop}}
       {{#each departures.departure}}
         {{> attributes}}
       {{/each}}
   </div>
</template>

<template name="attributes">
    <div class="attributes">
        {{content}}
        accurate : {{{access_attributes this}}}
    </div>
</template>
```

and on the js side :

```
Template.attributes.access_attributes = function(context) {
    return context["@attributes"].accurate
}
```